# Advice on rewrite regex

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would appreciate some help with URL rewriting within a .htaccess file.

I have this structure

```
http://foo.com/news/?start=24
http://foo.com/work/?start=24
```

I would like to be able rewrite what comes after .com if it be 'news' or 'work' and remove anything after the question mark.

Examples

```
http://foo.com/news/?start=24 => http://foo.com/news
http://foo.com/work/?start=24 => http://foo.com/work
```

Comment: Using what? .htaccess? A tool with regex support? A programming language? Which?

Comment: Within the .htaccess file, I will update post also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect also any other files in such path, such as `work/something?params`, then use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [^?]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{SERVER_PORT}s ^(.*):(443(s)|\d+s)$
RewriteRule ^/?(news|work)(/|$) http%3://%1/$1? [R=301,L]
```

or if you want no extra optional files to be included after `news` or `work`, then go with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [^?]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}:%{SERVER_PORT}s ^(.*):(443(s)|\d+s)$
RewriteRule ^/?(news|work)/?$ http%3://%1/$1? [R=301,L]
```